# Round arithmetic during evaluation

Tags: python, function, math, rounding

### Question

When evaluating arithmetic there are multiple steps (PEMDAS) taken during evaluation. I know you can evaluate an operation then round it, but at times you need to round your data to never exceed a certain precision throughout the evaluation. This brings me to my question: **How can you round at every step during the evaluation instead of just at the end?**

### Examples

For our first example, we will be using the simple operation `0.125/0.375` and rounding to 2 decimals.

```
# This operation evaluates to 1/3
>>> 0.125/0.375
0.3333333333333333

# If we wanted to round it we could just do
>>> round(0.125/0.375, 2)
0.33

# But if we wanted to round at every step of PEMDAS the following would be necessary
>>> round(round(0.125, 2)/round(0.375, 2), 2)
0.32

# Same equation as above but written as (1/8)/(3/8)
>>> round(round(round(1, 2)/round(8, 2), 2)/round(round(3, 2)/round(8, 2), 2), 2)
0.32
```

As you can see you get a different result if rounding is performed at every step rather than just at the end.

Although being a bit cumbersome this approach does get the job done. Problems arise though when the equation is not hardcoded but rather received from the user:

```
# Rounding cannot be applied here in the same way that we did above
>>> eval(input("Arithmetic: "))
Arithmetic: (1/8)/(3/8)
0.3333333333333333
```

### Use cases

This may seem pretty useless at first but can actually be very valuable for many things.
Here is a simple example where rounding at each step would be necessary for finding the holes of a function:

```
# undefined.py

from math import *
import numpy as np


function = input("Function in terms of x: ")


def is_undefined(x):
  x = round(x, 2)   # To deal with minor Python inaccuracies (ex: 1.000000000000001)
  try:
    eval(function)
    return False
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    return True


undefined = [x for x in np.linspace(-5, 5, 1001) if is_undefined(float(x))]
print(undefined)
```

```
# Works perfectly!
>>> python undefined.py
Function in terms of x: (x**2)*(x-2)/(x-2)
[2.0]

# Unable to find the hole at x=pi
>>> python undefined.py
Function in terms of x: (x**2)*(2*x - 2*pi)/(x - pi)
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `decimal` module provides a `Decimal` type which can be configured so that all arithmetic operations are rounded to a certain number of decimal places:

```py
>>> import decimal as d
>>> d.setcontext(d.Context(prec=2))
>>> x = d.Decimal(0.125)
>>> y = d.Decimal(0.375)
>>> x / y
Decimal('0.33')
```

You can force rounding of the numbers before the division by using the unary `+` operation, which normally does nothing, but in this case it applies the precision from the current context, changing the result (to be more inaccurate, of course):

```py
>>> (+x) / (+y)
Decimal('0.32')
```

So a solution for an expression from user input could be to replace all number literals and instances of the variable `x` with `Decimal` objects of the same values: here I've used a regular expression to do that, and to use a unary `+` to also force rounding before operations.

```py
import decimal as d
import re

d.setcontext(d.Context(prec=2))

function = input("Function in terms of x: ")
function = re.sub(r'([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|x)', r'(+d.Decimal(\1))', function)

# ...
```

Note there is no longer a need to write `x = round(x, 2)`, because the expression itself forces `x` to be rounded.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for symbolic math instead, such as [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html), which can probably do what you're really looking for-

Specifically, not aliasing transcendental numbers (like pi and e) or waiting to reduce irreducible fractions into decimal space until asked to [evaluate to a decimal](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html)

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> expr = "(1/8)/(3/8)"
>>> simplify(expr)           # precise value
1/3
>>> simplify(expr).evalf()   # decimal aliasing
0.333333333333333
>>> N("(1/8)/(3/8)")         # using sympy.N()
0.333333333333333
```

This can also be used to solve equations

```py
>>> x = symbols("x", real=True)
>>> solve(x**2 - 1)                         # simple solution
[-1, 1]
>>> solve(x**2 - pi)                        # more complex solution
[-sqrt(pi), sqrt(pi)]
>>> [N(expr) for expr in solve(x**2 - pi)]  # decimal approximation
[-1.77245385090552, 1.77245385090552]
```

This can also be used (perhaps evilly) with Python constructs

```py
>>> [N(x * pi) for x in range(10)]          # lots of approximations!
[0, 3.14159265358979, 6.28318530717959, 9.42477796076938, 12.5663706143592, 15.7079632679490, 18.8495559215388, 21.9911485751286, 25.1327412287183, 28.2743338823081]
```